# Granting external storage permissions without restarting the app

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, android-external-storage

For Android devices with API 23 or higher, how could I grant external storage permissions without restarting the app (kind of like the user's music library being uploaded to Google Play Music within a single session)? I know this issue has been addressed several times here in SO, but I'm not finding any luck so far.

Here are the permissions in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { // API 23
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

            return; // Included here to prevent the app from crashing.
        }
    }

    /**
     * CODE HERE FOR INSTANTIATIONS AND SUCH.
     */
}
```

... Because as of now, I'd need to restart the app for the permissions to go through (and MainActivity's instantiations and such) **after** accepting the permissions from the initial pop-up.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: "I'd need to restart the app for the permissions to go through" -- no, you do not. Move "CODE HERE FOR INSTANTIATIONS AND SUCH." into another method. Call that method from `onCreate()` if you happen to have permissions already at that point. Also call that method from `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, if the user agreed to those permissions. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Files/FilesEditor), for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CommonsWare suggested, you can put all your code which does *INSTANTIATIONS AND SUCH* in a method like `instantiateMyObjects()` and call that in the `onCreate()` like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { // API 23
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_CODE);
            // Define the constant MY_PERMISSION_CODE.

            return; // Included here to prevent the app from crashing.
        }
    }

    instantiateMyObjects();
}
```

And when user accepts/denies your permission request `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is called. Don't forget to define `MY_PERMISSION_CODE` take it as `1` for example.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Now you can instantiate your objects.
            instantiateMyObjects();
        } else {
            // User denied it.
        }
    }
}
```